# Context has no dynamic value while sending email with send_mail() in django

Tags: django, email-templates

I am trying to send mail with dynamic valued templates in django, But the parameter context sends nothing to the template

tasks.py

```
def send_verification_mail(username,mail):
    msg_html = render_to_string('templates/email.html',  
    {'context':"value","context2":"value2"})
    html=strip_tags(msg_html)
    send_mail(
        'From online store',
        'Welcome '+username,
        'praveenkumarstream@gmail.com',
        [mail],
        html_message=html,
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

email_template.html

```
<html>
    <body>To verify click below<br>
        <button> Verify your account</button>
{{context}} {{context2}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*But the parameter context sends nothing to the template*"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In the mail nothing in the area of {{context}} {{context2}} Note: Mail receives successfully